# jquery next previous for images

Tags: jquery

I want to make one image gallery where I just click anywhere in left half of image for previous photo and anywhere in  right side of photo for next photo.
 I have issue in setting up jQuery

I have this html code

```
<tr><td align="center" width="6%"><span id="picviewer-prev" class="picviewer-area"><span></span></span><strong><a id="picviewer-prev" onclick="jQuery.image({ ajax:    'http://way2enjoy.com/jquery/photolove/785' });return false;" href="#"><img align="absmiddle" src="js/left.png"></a></strong></td><td width="57%" align="center">
<div id="imgtag" style="width:600px;"><img src="/upload/media_files/00/00/00/47/51/4751.photo.jpg" style="max-width:600px;margin-bottom:-3px;"></div></td><td align="top" width="6%"><span id="picviewer-next" class="picviewer-area"><span></span></span><strong><a id="picviewer-next" onclick="jQuery.image({ ajax: 'http://way2enjoy.com/jquery/photolove/787' });return false;" href="#"><img align="absmiddle" src="js/right.png"></a></strong></td><td width="31%" valign="top" style="background:#fff;overflow:hidden;"></td><td width="400" valign="top" style="padding-left:30px"><div class="hr"></div></td></tr>
```

CSS code

```
  <style>
  #picviewer-prev 
  {
      left: -150px;
      right: 50%;
  }
  .picviewer-area {
      bottom: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 10;
  }

  #picviewer-next {
   left: 50%;
   right: -150px;
  }
  .picviewer-area {
   bottom: 0;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 10;
  }
  </style>
```

jQuery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function()

      { $("#picviewer-prev").click( prev );
     $("#picviewer-next").click( prev );

     });</script>
```

but when I click on image nothing happens. I think my jQuery is wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `click(prev)` ? Maybe you need to read more about jQuery...

Comment: Damn, you need to learn jQuery first, my friend. in the `click` parameters you should have a function.

Comment: @In God I Trust OR a reference to a function, which that appears to be. (example: http://jsfiddle.net/SpAm/Hwr7P/)

Comment: @suhani As these guys are saying, you HTML and your JS don't appear to go together. You're defining an onclick event twice.
Can you provide the prev() function if indeed it is a function. Or if not, please follow the advise of In God I Trust and Steve...

Comment: @MasNotsram correct, I assumed from the lack of code that `prev` was undefined!

Comment: @InGodITrust can u plz help in my jquery. i am learning jquery but if u can help it will be grt help

Comment: @Steve can u plz help in my jquery. i am learning jquery but if u can help it will be grt help

Comment: @suhani start with more simple things. Don't try to start by the roof. Start trying to hide and show elements, texts...etc and you will improve looking specific questions on the net. Good luck.

Comment: @suhani take a course maybe on Lynda, start at more simple things, functions like `$(this).click(function(){alert('I was clicked')});`

Comment: @InGodITrust in my case what jquery will be theere can u plz tell

Comment: @suhani pleasure, sorry cant help with code